# how can I define the next morning after user registration in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to schedule some notifications for three month after user registration. Though, first of all I need to define the first morning after registration.
Could you help me?

Comment: Please show that you have had a go - write some code and post it.

Comment: Get the time stamp of registration from your server, Convert it to NSDate. Split it into NSDateComponents. Add three months to month component. Create new date from those components. Schedule a local notification for that NSDate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Schedule a local notification.

```
let localNotif = UILocalNotification()
let calendar = NSCalendar.autoupdatingCurrentCalendar()
let dateComps = NSDateComponents()

dateComps.day = registrationDate.day
dateComps.month = registrationDate.month
dateComps.year = registrationDate.year
dateComps.hour = 9
dateComps.minute = 0

let itemDate = calendar.dateFromComponents(dateComps)

localNotif.fireDate = itemDate.dateByAddingTimeInterval(24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0)
localNotif.timeZone = NSTimeZone.defaultTimeZone()

localNotif.alertBody = "Good Morning new user!"
localNotif.alertAction = "View details"
localNotif.alertTitle = "Good morning"

localNotif.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
localNotif.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1

UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(localNotif)
```

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/IPhoneOSClientImp.html

Comment: I just need to define the next 7 AM after registration whether it is at 1:00 or 18:00. The next 7 Am could be about 24 hours later or even 2 hours later.

Comment: As you can see I have set the time to 9:00 in the registration day in my example. Then I add 24 hour to that date so it's always 9:00 in the next morning.

Comment: Oh, Thanks. it works for me. Now, how can I make it work as a loop for one month? I mean, sending different strings three times each day.

Comment: Just schedule several notifications with different texts. You can make a notification recurring by setting the "repeatInterval" property.